# Why pandas chunks are behaving differently then actual dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to process a CSV file present on my local hard disk in chunks using pandas. I have the processing code ready and it works without any error if I ran the code on a whole dataset. The problem arises when the same code is run on the chunks.

I thought maybe the chunks are of different data types so tried checking the type of chunks using `type(chunk)` and it is the same as `type(whole_dataframe)`.

What I tried:

```
whole_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=0)

whole_data['cuisines'] = whole_data.cuisines.apply(lambda x: ','+x)
```

This gives me the expected result. But when I try running the same code on chunks as:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=0, chunksize=1000):
    chunk['cuisines'] = chunk.cuisines.apply(lambda x: ','+x)
```

This gives me an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

I expect the output to be the same as output I got while running the code on the whole dataset.

Comment: can you share the csv

Comment: I am sorry I can't it is sensitive data from my office. But if you are wondering the data type of each cell/value, its same across the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=0, chunksize=1000):
    chunk['cuisines'] = chunk.cuisines.apply(lambda x: ','+str(x))
```

Even better:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=0, chunksize=1000):
    chunk['cuisines'] = ',' + chunk.cuisines.astype(str).str
```

Comment: The first part works for me, second works only if I remove '.str' from the end. I think you have it by mistake. Nonetheless, your logic says that I should change each value as type string first and then do the add operation. But why it is needed, I have already checked the data type of 'cuisines' column and is of type string